# Javascript find the word and replace in an input by button click

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

There are 4 input text.

The first input you can write something randomly like "Hi Ann".
The second input find this word: "Ann".
The thirth input text replace this word "Dan".
The fourth input text the new sense "Hi Dan".

This has the do with button replace

If nothing is been written then it should show an alert "fill in please"
If the word cannot be found the fourth input should show "The word cannot be found!"

If I remember it well it should be something the do with 2 functions I think.

I am trying it but sadly can't figure it out.

Anyone who can help me out? I kind of new into javascript.

```js
let zinTxt;
let allexCorrectIngevuld;
let zoek;

function verstuur() {
zinTxt = document.getElementById("zin").value;
allesCorrectIngevuld = true;

if(zinTxt == 0) {
alert(document.getElementById("zin_error").innerHTML="fill in something please");
allesCorrectIngevuld = false;
}
}

function vervangWoord() {
zoek = document.getElementById("zoek").value;
}
```

```html
<form>

<p>

<label for="zin">Type here your words:</label>
<input type="text" id="zin"/>
<span class="error" id="zin_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="zoek">Find this word:</label>
<input type="text" id="zoek"/>
<span class="error" id="zoek_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="plaats">This word will be replace:</label>
<input type="text" id="plaats"/>
<span class="error" id="plaats_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<input type="button" value="replace" id="knop" onclick="verstuur()" />

</p>

<p>
<label for="nieuwe">These are the new sense:</label>
<input type="text" id="nieuwe"/>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: if(zinTxt == "") to check if the input is empty
And why use a alert? document.getElementById("zin_error").innerHTML="fill in something please" is enougth

Answer (score 0):

to check if a string is empty use "".

```js
let zinTxt;
let allexCorrectIngevuld;
let zoek;

function verstuur() {
zinTxt = document.getElementById("zin").value;
allesCorrectIngevuld = true;

if(zinTxt == "") {
document.getElementById("zin_error").innerHTML="fill in something please";
allesCorrectIngevuld = false;
}
}

function vervangWoord() {
zoek = document.getElementById("zoek").value;
}
```

```html
<form>

<p>

<label for="zin">Type here your words:</label>
<input type="text" id="zin"/>
<span class="error" id="zin_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="zoek">Find this word:</label>
<input type="text" id="zoek"/>
<span class="error" id="zoek_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="plaats">This word will be replace:</label>
<input type="text" id="plaats"/>
<span class="error" id="plaats_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<input type="button" value="replace" id="knop" onclick="verstuur()" />

</p>

<p>
<label for="nieuwe">These are the new sense:</label>
<input type="text" id="nieuwe"/>
</p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions. The most basic implementation would look like below.

```js
const zin = document.getElementById("zin");
const zinError = document.getElementById("zin_error");
const zoek = document.getElementById("zoek");
const plaats = document.getElementById("plaats");
const nieuwe = document.getElementById("nieuwe");

function verstuur() { 
  zinError.innerHTML="";
  
  if (zin.value === "") {
    zinError.innerHTML="fill in something please";
    return false;
  }

  if (!zin.value.includes(zoek.value)) {
    nieuwe.value = "The word cannot be found!";
    return false;
  }

  nieuwe.value = zin.value.replace(zoek.value, plaats.value);
}
```

```html
<form>

<p>

<label for="zin">Type here your words:</label>
<input type="text" id="zin"/>
<span class="error" id="zin_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="zoek">Find this word:</label>
<input type="text" id="zoek"/>
<span class="error" id="zoek_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<label for="plaats">This word will be replace:</label>
<input type="text" id="plaats"/>
<span class="error" id="plaats_error"></span>

</p>

<p>

<input type="button" value="replace" id="knop" onclick="verstuur()" />

</p>

<p>
<label for="nieuwe">These are the new sense:</label>
<input type="text" id="nieuwe"/>
</p>

</form>
```